# Python unorderable types: NoneType() > int() when finding max of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started with python 3 few days back. While programming, I came across strange situation

```
a = [
     [5, [[1, 1, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], 
     [5, [[1, None, 1], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
    ]
```

`max(a)` gives me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()

But if I try

```
a = [
     [5, [[1, 1, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], 
     [5.1, [[1, None, 1], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
    ]
```

`max(a)` displays

```
[5.1, [[1, None, 1], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
```

Any particular reason for this behaviour?

Update 1:
I tried with something different

```
 a = [[5, [[1,2], [3,4]]],[5,[[3,4],[5,10]]],[5,[[5,6],[7,8]]]]
```

and `max(a)` is `[5, [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]`
My doubt is why the error is not showing in this case?

Comment: Which part are you confused by? If the first elements of the lists aren't equal, there's no need to tie break with the second element.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: okay.. my doubt is why python showing me the error? 
For ```[[5, [[1,2], [3,4]]],[5,[[3,4],[5,6]]],[5,[[5,6],[7,8]]]]
``` the output is ```[5, [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]``` and why the same error is not showing?

Comment: Why did you think you would get the same error? What unorderable types does that example contain?

Comment: you cannot mix unorderable types together and expect that `max` will work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: thanks.. It's clear now. Basically max compares each item in the list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: My doubt is solved..

Comment: I still don't know what your doubt was. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you only have positive numbers, just change `None` into `0` and you're good to go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I was unaware that max() compares each and every item in list if necessary. So max of ```int``` and ```None``` was causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `max` does this when it encounters None values:

```
max([1, None])
```

also gives the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c33cf47436bc> in <module>()
----> 1 max([1,None])

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

Basically max is trying to iterate over the list and find out the larger value first. But as it reaches None it can't compare any more so throws error.

with

```
a = [
     [5, [[1, 1, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]], 
     [5.1, [[1, None, 1], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]]
    ]
```

it compares 5 and 5.1 and considers list with 5.1 as bigger.

While when both first values were 5 it went to iterate the next item and ran into `None` which caused the error.

Update:

This example might help clarify the error message even better:

```
max([1,'2'])
```

error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

basically it tried to compare `'2' with 1` and gave `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`

earlier we were comparing `None with int() 1` and error message we got was `TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, this `None` trick which compared lower to any integer was useful in some cases, when you needed a minimum value you couldn't predict (as integers don't have a fixed min/max like in C).

In Python 3 this isn't possible anymore (and most of the time it's for the best, it saves a lot of headaches when comparing strings to integers like `"2"` and 3 for instance.

If you really need that, I thought of a workaround.

You could define a class which is lower than any other object and use an instance of that class instead of `None`:

```
class AM:
    def __int__(self):
        return 0
    def __gt__(self,other):
        return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return "INF"   # prints out nicely

always_min = AM()

a = [
     [5, [[1, 1, always_min], [always_min, always_min, always_min]]],
     [5, [[1, always_min, 1], [always_min, always_min, always_min]]]
    ]

print(max(a))
```

I get:

```
[5, [[1, 1, INF], [INF, INF, INF]]]
```

which proves that tiebreak worked.

Note that this is a minimal implementation. `max` only uses >: defining only `__gt__` is lazy, we'd need to define others `__ge__`, `__le__`, `__lt__` accordingly for a general usage.